# Am I understanding PyTorch's add_ and mul_ correctly?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, data-science

In [this notebook](https://github.com/davidcpage/cifar10-fast/blob/master/bag_of_tricks.ipynb) the author writes the following [nesterov update](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179915/whats-the-difference-between-momentum-based-gradient-descent-and-nesterovs-acc):

```
def nesterov_update(w, dw, v, lr, weight_decay, momentum):
    dw.add_(weight_decay, w).mul_(-lr)
    v.mul_(momentum).add_(dw)
    w.add_(dw.add_(momentum, v))
```

As I understand it, `a.add(b)` in PyTorch implements `a+b` and `a.add(b,c)` implements `a+(b*c)`, because `b` is in the slot of the [alpha parameter](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.add.html). And lastly, `add_` does the in-place version of `add`.

**Q: Am I right so far?**

Then, if I were to sketch the above nesterov update in an expanded form that illustrates the logic, I would write:

```
dw = -lr*(dw + weight_decay*w)
v = v*momentum + dw
w = w + dw + momentum*v
```

**Q: is this correct?**

I'm not planning to use the above expanded "code," I'm just writing it this way to try communicate what I'm understanding that it's doing, to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to note the PyTorch version (1.1.0) the tutorial is using. According to 1.1.0, function prototype for [torch.add](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/torch.html#torch.add) is `torch.add(input, value=1, other, out=None)`. So, your interpretation of the following line:

```
dw.add_(weight_decay, w)
```

as: `dw = dw + weight_decay * w` is correct. So, the answer to your first question is, yes, you are right.

However, with the latest versions of PyTorch, you would get an error if [torch.add](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=add#torch.add) is used in the same fashion.

```
a = torch.FloatTensor([0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
b = torch.FloatTensor([0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0])
c = 1.0
z = a.add(b, c)
```

The above code gives: (**In PyTorch 1.5.0**)

```
TypeError: add() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

However, if you perform the following, then it works fine.

```
z = a.add(b, alpha=c)
```

Note that, the prototype of [torch.add](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=add#torch.add) is now: `torch.add(input, other, *, alpha=1, out=None)`

---

The answer to your second question is, yes, you are right.